# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine : Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I created ASP.NET core 6 API project and used JWT authentication for each API end point.
But while executing in some physical system works fine but some other physical system and server throws below error

```
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
```

Sample Code

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
var token = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async() => await new Token("URL", "username", "pwd"])).Result;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.Method = "POST";
var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Details, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var responses = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Sample code based on HTTP Client

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), endpoint))
                    {
                        string token = SalesOperationAPIToken("url", "usertest", "pwd");
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Details);
                        request.Content = new StringContent(json);
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                        var responseMessage = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
```

I am not sure what configuration need to be changed to get this worked in all system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by using HttpClient and not the ancient HttpWebRequest.

Comment: @CodeCaster tried that too. but not working. i have included that code sample also in initial message for reference.

Comment: _"in some physical system works fine but some other physical system and server throws below error"_ - then find out the differences between them. Perhaps there's a proxy server in between that doesn't speak HTTPS or something like that.